# Determining size for text in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm a little confused about using font attributes and sizeWithAttributes in iOS 7.

Apparently, this does not work correctly, because the size returned, if used, clips my text.

e.g.

```
NSDictionary * attributes = label.font.fontDescriptor.fontAttributes;
CGSize labelSize = [str sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
```

What is the correct way to get all of the font attributes required for sizeWithAttributes, if not font.fontDescriptor.fontAttributes?

Comment: Are you calling `ceil()` on the returned coordinates, as mentioned e.g. [here](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/string-rendering.html#displaying_dynamic_text_in_a_table_view)? That could account for a couple of pixels’ worth of clipping.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't, but the size returned was WAY off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the attributes of the font to the sizeWithAttributes, instead you need to pass the desired attributes of the string. Change the second line to

```
CGSize labelSize = [str sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : label.font}];
```

Comment: Thank you!I'm still a little confused by why passing the attributes of the font don't specify the desired attributes for the string in this situation.  The attributes of the font contain the name of the font and the text size.  I take it that the method just can't work with those to re-determine the font, and... it returns values based on the default font, maybe?

Comment: Problem for the future:  XCode says that UITextAttributeFont is deprecated in iOS 7.  So that really does still leave my question unanswered: what is the proper way to do this in iOS 7?

Comment: The font is just one of the attributes that you can specify for the string. from the documentation for sizeWithAttributes - " These are the same attributes that can be applied to an NSAttributedString object". The list of keys is given at NSAttributedString UIKit additions documentation , section - CharacterAttributes. Changed the key name to the correct one